# Test Edit action with viewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq, automapper

I have the following controller action

```
public ActionResult EditFocus(int id)
    {
        var Focus = focusService.GetFocus(id);
        Mapper.CreateMap<Focus, FocusFormModel>()
        FocusFormModel editFocus = Mapper.Map<Focus, FocusFormModel>(Focus);
        if (Focus == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View("EditFocus", editFocus);
```

i am using Nunit for testing. And the test is

```
 [Test]
public void Edit_Get_ReturnsView()
{


    FocusFormModel group = new FocusFormModel() { FocusId = 1, FocusName = "Test" };
    Mapper.CreateMap<Focus, FocusFormModel>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
    Focus focusViewModel = Mapper.Map<Focus, FocusFormModel>(group);
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    focusRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(1)).Returns(focusViewModel);

    FocusController controller = new GroupController(focusService);
    ViewResult actual = controller.EditFocus(1) as ViewResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual, "View Result is null");
```

}

but the test fails
In the NUnit GUI I get the following error:

```
Missing Mapping type Configuration& Unsupported Mapping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the mapping twice.  It should only be done once for **web** and **tests**.

**web**: only create your maps once on application start, possibly using [profiles](http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2012/08/27/organizing-automappers-map-configurations-in-mvc/).

**tests**: create maps in TestFixtureSetUp in specific test or in base Test class if you have one.

Comment: second line of your test creates map, then you call editFocus of controller which also creates map.